# Android ZoomControl layout

Tags: java, android, testing, layout, android-espresso

I'm testing my android app with espresso and want to test the ZoomControls like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.zoomIn)).perform(click());
```

But I don't get the zoomIn/zoomOut id, from the Zoom_Controls. In the Layout Component Tree, the zoomIn and zoomOut are visible.

[image]

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

```
Resources res = Resources.getSystem();
int id = res.getIdentifier("btn_zoom_down", "drawable", "android");
```

Didn't work.

Got it working with:

```java
Resources res = Resources.getSystem();
int id = res.getIdentifier("@id/zoomOut", "drawable", "android");
onView(withId(id)).perform(click());
```